# how to get specific transform attribute in D3

Tags: d3.js, transform

All:

I wonder how can I get SVG individual transform attribute such as:
Translate Scale etcs rather than the whole transform string in D3.

Like in style, I can use style("background-color") to get individual background color rather than the whole style string.

Is there any similar API or method can be applied to transform attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`d3.transform()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Math#d3_transform), e.g.

```
var t = d3.transform(element.attr("transform"));
t.translate;
```

Comment: Thanks for help, could you give a simple example?

Comment: Well what are you looking for? I've put a code sample in my answer.

Comment: @ Lars Kotthoff  Thanks, could you give a simple example how to flip a rectangle by click a button with what you talk about? In a 400 by 400 svg, initially put a rectangle(top:100 left:100) (width:50, height:100). Then click a button, flip it horizontally to (top:100 left:250) based on x=200 flip line

Comment: That's a completely different question! On click, set `rectangle.attr("transform", "translate(250,100)")`.

Comment: Well, actually, it does not have to be a rectangle, it could be any shape, so I can not use simple translate

Comment: It sounds like you should ask a separate question about this. You may also find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899718/scale-and-mirror-svg-object) helpful.

Comment: For the d3 v4 version, see this other SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224875/replacing-d3-transform-in-d3-v4 . Thanks for the right direction @LarsKotthoff of getting the transform like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the attributes to move the rectangle where ever you want :)

```
 var rect = d3.select('rect')
    .attr('x', 400) //move in x direction 
    .attr('y', 200) //move in y direction
    ;
```

Or transform :

```
var shape = 'rect' //or any other shape SVG shape you want to select
var x = 200, y= 300; // translate variables

    var rect = d3.select(shape)
    //.attr("transform", "translate(x,y)")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well, I just wonder how to do this in transform

Comment: Thanks, It is kinda the way I want.  My problem is how to GET specific attribute of transform rather than SET it, however, this helps as well.