# Direction of markers in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, markers

For a school project I'm working on a force directed layout with markers. Now I don't know how to change the direction of the markers ... When i implemented them most of them were immediatly in the right direction but some of them need to be reversed. Does anyone know if there is an easy way to do this ?

```
 //defining the markers
      svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
     .data(["normal", "reverse"])
     .enter().append("marker")
     .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
     .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
     .attr("refX", 19)
     .attr("markerWidth", 6)
     .attr("markerHeight", 6)
     .attr("orient", "auto")
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

//Drawing the markers
     var edgeSelection = svg.selectAll('.edge')
    .data(edges)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .classed('edge', true)
    .style("marker-start",  "url()")
    .style("marker-end",  "url(#normal)")
    .call(positionEdge, nodes);
```

I have been playing around with "marker-start" ,"marker-end", "orient" and "refX" but I can't get it to work ...

Thanks

Comment: You would need to define the marker path reversed as well, e.g. by [mirroring it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899718/scale-and-mirror-svg-object).

Comment: Show us your data in order to be able to help you out.